# Copy the "Component code" in different sheet with respective to their sum of consumption

Tags: excel, vba

In the "BOM" Sheet I have the components code which are repeating multiple times in Bom sheet and the components code have different "comp qty" in front of them. So I want the copy the components code in my "Source" sheet only one time and sum the consumption against the single component code.
In "source" sheet there is only one component code with sum of "comp qty" in front of them. no duplication of component code in source sheet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yZz0.png)
This is my data. I have used one code but the problem is the range is static. I want that code run in "BOM" sheet till the last row and copy the component codes in "Source" sheet with respective to their sum of consumption.
One more thing there are multiple columns in "BOM" sheet so this is also copying all the column in my source file. so I want two columns in "Source" which are component code and comp qty
The code that I used is run for static range. I want to run till the last bom sheet. Kindly guide me.
Thank you in advance.

Private Sub consolidatedata()

```
Dim this As Variant
Dim that(3000, 1) As String
Dim rowC As Long
Dim colC As Long

this = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").UsedRange
rowC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").UsedRange.Rows.Count
colC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM").UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim thisname As String
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim x As Long

For i = LBound(this, 1) To UBound(this, 1)
    thisname = this(i, 1)

    For x = LBound(that, 1) To UBound(that, 1)
        If thisname = that(x, 0) Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf thisname <> that(x, 0) And that(x, 0) = vbNullString Then
            that(x, 0) = thisname
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
Next i

For i = LBound(that, 1) To UBound(that, 1)
    thisname = that(i, 0)
    For j = LBound(this, 1) To UBound(this, 1)
        If this(j, 1) = thisname Then
            thisvalue = thisvalue + this(j, 2)
        End If
    Next j
    that(i, 1) = thisvalue
    thisvalue = 0
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Cells(rowC, colC)).Value2 = that
```

End Sub

Comment: One more thing there are multiple columns in "BOM" sheet so this is also copying all the column in my source file. so I want two columns in "Source" which are component code and comp  qty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Unique Sum-Up Using a Dictionary

- To simplify, it is assumed that the range has at least two rows and the value column's cells are numeric.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateData()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "BOM"
    Const suCol As Long = 1 ' Unique Column Index
    Const svCol As Long = 4 ' Value Column Index
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Source"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Both
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Use a dictionary to keep track of when to write to columns
    ' and when to just sum up.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    ' Write headers.
    Data(1, 1) = Data(1, suCol)
    Data(1, 2) = Data(1, svCol)
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' new destination row (skip headers)
    
    Dim sKey As Variant ' current value in source unique column
    Dim sr As Long ' current source row
    Dim dcr As Long ' destination row when summing up
    
    For sr = 2 To UBound(Data, 1) ' skip headers
        sKey = Data(sr, suCol)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                If dict.Exists(sKey) Then ' already in dictionary
                    dcr = dict(sKey) ' read the 'item' i.e. the destination row
                    ' Only sum up.
                    Data(dcr, 2) = Data(dcr, 2) + Data(sr, svCol)
                Else
                    dr = dr + 1 ' new destination row
                    ' Write the new unique value and new destination row
                    ' to the 'key' and 'item' respectively.
                    dict(sKey) = dr
                    ' Write the values from the two columns to the first columns
                    ' of the destination row.
                    Data(dr, 1) = Data(sr, suCol)
                    Data(dr, 2) = Data(sr, svCol)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Write the modified values from the array to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        ' Clear previous data.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Clear
        ' Write new data.
        .Resize(dr, 2).Value = Data
    End With
    
    'wb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data consolidated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

### EDIT

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateDataMoreColumns()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "BOM"
    Const suCol As Long = 1 ' Unique Column Index
    Const svCol As Long = 2 ' Value Column Index
    Dim soCols As Variant: soCols = VBA.Array(3) ' Other Column Indexes
    ' To add more columns, use e.g. soCols = VBA.Array(3, 4)
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Source"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Both
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Use a dictionary to keep track of when to write to columns
    ' and when to just sum up.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim soUpper As Long: soUpper = UBound(soCols)
    Dim so As Long
    
    ' Write headers.
    Data(1, 1) = Data(1, suCol)
    Data(1, 2) = Data(1, svCol)
    For so = 0 To soUpper
        Data(1, so + 3) = Data(1, soCols(so))
    Next so
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' new destination row (skip headers)
    
    Dim sKey As Variant ' current value in source unique column
    Dim sr As Long ' current source row
    Dim dcr As Long ' destination row when summing up
    
    For sr = 2 To UBound(Data, 1) ' skip headers
        sKey = Data(sr, suCol)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                If dict.Exists(sKey) Then ' already in dictionary
                    dcr = dict(sKey) ' read the 'item' i.e. the destination row
                    ' Only sum up.
                    Data(dcr, 2) = Data(dcr, 2) + Data(sr, svCol)
                Else
                    dr = dr + 1 ' new destination row
                    ' Write the new unique value and new destination row
                    ' to the 'key' and 'item' respectively.
                    dict(sKey) = dr
                    ' Write the values from the columns to the first columns
                    ' of the destination row.
                    Data(dr, 1) = Data(sr, suCol)
                    Data(dr, 2) = Data(sr, svCol)
                    For so = 0 To soUpper
                        Data(dr, so + 3) = Data(sr, soCols(so))
                    Next so
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Write the modified values from the array to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        ' Clear previous data.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Clear
        ' Write new data.
        .Resize(dr, soUpper + 3).Value = Data
    End With
    
    'wb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data consolidated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```